# Extracting data from n-n relation on the same table

Tags: mysql, sql

I need some help on a little problem I have in SQL.
I have currently Wamp server 32bit with MySQL 5.6.12
I have two tables, one that contain id (primary key) and other stuff, and a second table that is the result of a n-n relationship on the first table to indicate that some bug can be a clone of another.

What I need to do is:
take out a list of bugs with a field that have the “cloned” bug’s id next to it.

What I already have:
I have a part of the solution, I succeed to attach some of the cloned bug to one bug and take the cloned bug out of the list, I would like to give you the actual code, but I dont have it right now but here something looks like it (by memory):

```
select bug_table.id, clones_table.clone
from bug_table 
left outer join 
(
    select source_bug_id, Group_Concat(DISTINC cast(destination_bug_id AS string)) as clone
    from relationship_table
    Group by source_bug_id
)  clones_table
On bug_table_id=source_bug_id
where id not in
(
    select destination_bug_id
    from relationship_table
)
```

This query is made from 2 sub query, the first one is for adding the list of “clone id” to the “origin id”, the seconde is for removing those “clone id” from the actual results
So my problem is: it only look in one side of the table for clones, I don’t know how to explain it with words, so let’s take example
Let’s say I have 4 bugs, so they have for id 1,2,3,4 and they are all clones of eachother
In my relationship_table I have

```
source_bug_id   |destination_bug_id  
1               |2  
1               |3  
1               |4
```

So if I throw my query with this, it should and will output this :

```
id      |clone  
1       |2,3,4
```

Exactly what I want , but if the table contain this :

```
source_bug_id   |destination_bug_id  
1               |2  
3               |2  
4               |2
```

It will output me

```
id      |clone  
1       |2  
3       |2  
4       |2
```

And, surely, it’s not what I want…
What I have already though about for solving my problem:
In my query, I could try add a sub query ,replacing "from relationship_table" to prepare the table in a good shape, I think it could be like something like

```
(
    select * 
    from relationship_table
    group by destination_bug_id
)
union
(
    select t1.destination_bug_id , t2.source_bug_id
    from relationship_table as t1 inner join relationship_table as t2 on t1.destination_bug_id = t2.source_bug_id
    where t1.source_bug_id not in
    (
        select source_bug_id
        from relationship_table
        group by destination_bug_id
    )
)
```

I didn’t tested it but the first sub query should group all destination_bug_id to be sure that they are unique, and the second add it the missing row reverted maybe :/

I've searched but I’m not really familiar with English terms so maybe I could miss a subject that give me the answer.

Comment: what result you want to get for your second example?

Comment: it should output the same as the first example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you want to do that in SQL?

What happens if bug1 is a clone of bug2, bug2 being a clone of bug3, etc.. :

```
Id    CloneId
1        2
2        3
3        4
```

You should want the result

```
Id     Clones
1      2, 3, 4
```

This becomes a recursive search, and it will be very complicated in SQL. Maybe you want to do that in PHP or whatever language you are using.

For your case, here is a query that only invert the fields, it gives you a partial result:

```
select source_bug_id, 
       Group_Concat(destination_bug_id) as clone
from
(
  (
      select source_bug_id, destination_bug_id
      from relationship_table
  )
  union
  (
      select destination_bug_id, source_bug_id
      from relationship_table
  )
) as alls
group by source_bug_id

SOURCE_BUG_ID       CLONE
1                   2
2                   1,3,4
3                   2
4                   2
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b8b85/11/0)

Comment: I've got exatly the same thought as you before you post, i didn't though of this case when i beginned my research, but it's sure it will be very complicated (if not impossible) if i need to have recursive search. Going ahead for doing this in php, shouldn't be hard. Thanks for taking time for me.